# how to return a multidimensional array from a method in another class

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in a method in another class. I want to return this array (copy it) so that I can manipulate its value in my `MainActivity`. The following code gives the following error:

> Attempt to Read a Null Array

which shows that the array is not returned. Pls note that I am novice in Android java... Thank you all for your time and answers..

Array Declarations inside the class are as follows:

```
String[][] arapozisyon = {
            {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2"},
            {"a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7"},
            {"a1", "h1"},
            {"a8", "h8"},
            {"b1", "g1"},
            {"b8", "g8"},
            {"c1", "f1"},
            {"c8", "f8"},
            {"d1"},
            {"d8"},
            {"e1"},
            {"e8"}
    };
    static String[][][] pozisyon;
```

The `pozisyon [][][]` array will be filled with `arapozisyon[][]` array. The code does that, there is no problem with that.

This is the return statement in side the method:

```
public String[][][] pozisyonHazirla(String param, int param1) {

.
.
.
return pozisyon;
}
```

And here is how try to retrieve it on my MainActicvity code:

```
pozisyonKlasi hamleGonder = new pozisyonKlasi();  // The class where the method is placed...


    String[][][] gelPozisyon = pozisyonKlasi.pozisyon;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gelPozisyon[1][0].length; j++) { // Error line
                String kare = gelPozisyon[1][0][j];
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(kare, "id", getPackageName());
                ImageView ll = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
                ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wp);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and looking into what the array actually contains that you get returned?

Comment: I checked the length and returned strings from the array and printed them in a textview. The problem started when I tried to return the whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pozisyon` is not inited.

Where do you call the method `pozisyonHazirla(String param, int param1)`?

Comment: Hello, inside    Public class pozisyonKlasi{ - Here- } This is where it is located.

Comment: instead of `String[][][] gelPozisyon = pozisyonKlasi.pozisyon;`

try `String[][][] gelPozisyon = pozisyonKlasi.pozisyonHazirla(param,param1);`

Comment: The code is exactly as that. When I write => pozisyonKlasi hamleGonder = new pozisyonKlasi();
                        String[][][] gelPozisyon = hamleGonder.pozisyonHazirla(gonderilecekHamle, don2);  I get the following error =>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray/chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                        Toast.makeText(this, gelPozisyon.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: try `Toast.makeText(this, ""+ gelPozisyon.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); `

Comment: `gelPozisyon.length` is an integer so you are calling the wrong method that fetch the ressource from you R.java

Comment: Dear Boukharist, this works. I spent 2 days doing nothing and now I am back on track. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the array make a method in the other class like this

```
String[][] arapozisyon;

    public Array getArray(){
        arapozisyon = {
            {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2"},
            {"a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7"},
            {"a1", "h1"},
            {"a8", "h8"},
            {"b1", "g1"},
            {"b8", "g8"},
            {"c1", "f1"},
            {"c8", "f8"},
            {"d1"},
            {"d8"},
            {"e1"},
            {"e8"}
    return arapozisyon;
}
```

Then call this method from the other class before you actually want to use it that way now the array is populated

Comment: I populate the pozisyon array with arapozisyon array like this => pozisyon = new String[donsay + 1][][];
        if (donsay == 0) {
            pozisyon[0] = arapozisyon;
        }

Comment: but were are you calling that from the other class? It needs to be initialized first so the other classes and methods can use it. please post your code on where you are calling the array from the other class to init it.

Comment: I thought that the code the following code above was enough: pozisyonKlasi hamleGonder = new pozisyonKlasi();  // The class where the method is placed...


    String[][][] gelPozisyon = pozisyonKlasi.pozisyon;

Comment: If your saying arapozisyon  is in the pozisyonKlasi class than all you are doing is creating and instance of the class this means you now have an empty object you still need to call a method that will return the array populated

Comment: The original code was =>  public String pozisyonHazirla(String param, int param1) {... when I could return a result String and I could even return the length of pozisyon. Then how can I reach pozisyon array which is inside another class and method from my MainActivity??

Comment: Thank you and all the others for their comments. It was a very specific problem. ...Regards